# Obtener veces que un equipo a ganado a otro con mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo esta tabla en mysql en la cual se guardan resultados de juegos realizados
para este caso se refiere al béisbol, como pueden ver en esta tabla tengo estos campos para el registro de cada resultado:

```
id_visitante -> equipo que actuó como visitante
visitante -> carreras realizadas por el equipo visitante
local -> carreras realizadas por el equipo local
id_local -> equipo que actuó como local
```

```
id_dominio  id_visitante   visitante    local   id_local    id_temporada
    1           1             0          10        3            1
    2           2             8          5         4            1
    3           6             2          15        7            1
    4           11            8          2         13           1
    5           3             8          2         1            1
    6           2             3          7         11           1
    7           7             5          0         4            1
    8           1             0          6         3            1
    9           13            7          1         8            1
    10          4             4          10        7            1
```

Lo que necesito es obtener el total de juegos que un equipo ha ganado a otro en los enfrentamientos que ha habido entre ellos.

Por ejemplo en las veces que se han enfrentado el 1 vs 3, cuantas veces ha ganado el 3

Hasta este momento he logrado obtener los resultados dados entre dos mismos equipos pero no el dominio que hay entre esos dos equipos

```
SELECT *  FROM dominio WHERE (id_local = 3 AND id_visitante = 1) OR (id_local = 1 AND id_visitante = 3) AND id_temporada = 1
```

Comment: y solo te falta comparar esos resultados, cuidando que siempre sean para el mismo lado ;)

Comment: @gbianchi pero como lo haría??

Comment: Podes usar esa query como entrada de una nueva query..

Comment: No entiendo mucho la pregunta. ¿Quieres obtener en la consulta el equipo que ha obtenido más victorias en los enfrentamientos entre ellos o quieres obtener las veces que cada uno ha ganado al otro?

Comment: @A.Cedano quiero obtener las veces que cada uno ha ganado al otro

Comment: @JorgeAlonso eso es lo que hace la consulta de más abajo. En la columna `OneWins` te dirá las veces que el equipo uno ha ganado al equipo 3 y en la columna `ThreeWins` te dirá las veces que el equipo 3 le ha ganado a él. Precisamente, así se maneja de forma adecuada la situación del empate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una aproximación basada en `SUM` usando `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN (id_visitante=1 AND id_local=3 AND visitante > local) OR (id_local=1 AND id_visitante=3 AND local > visitante) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS OneWins,
SUM(CASE 
             WHEN (id_visitante=3 AND id_local=1 AND visitante > local) OR (id_local=3 AND id_visitante=1 AND local > visitante) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS ThreeWins 
FROM match_results WHERE id_temporada=1;
```

Esta consulta crea dos columnas `OneWins` y `ThreeWins` y en cada una de ellas mostrará la cantidad de veces que el equipo 1 le ganó al equipo 3 y viceversa.

Un contexto interesante es el del empate. En este tipo de consultas, suponiendo que ambos equipos hayan ganado al otro `5` veces, el resultado sería este:

```
OneWins  |   ThreeWins
----------------------
    5    |       5
```

Saco a la luz esta posibilidad del empate porque podría complicar cualquier código si lo que te interesa es saber el equipo que domina al otro. En ese caso lo mejor será crear una función que verifique la cantidad de victorias de cada equipo cuando se enfrenta al otro, que verifique si son iguales para devolver un resultado `0` u otro o devuelva el equipo que domina al otro y la cantidad de victorias sobre este.